# Turn off tab completion in php interactive shell

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I've read the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php which mentions tab completion but nothing about configuration options for the cli.  Problems arise when I try to copy and paste code with tabs in it and the parser tries to do completion multiple times in the middle of a block.

Can I turn off tab completion in a php interactive shell?  If not, is there a way to paste my content without editing out all the tabs first?

Comment: What terminal program are you using? I'm pretty sure the one I have (iterm) does something similar (removes or converts new lines or something like that). So it's definitely a feature that exists in spirit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop this behavior, register an auto complete function that returns no matches to auto complete.

```
function dontAutoComplete ($input, $index)
{ return ([]); }

readline_completion_function ("dontAutoComplete");
```